# AtributeError "module" object has no atribute %name%

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi im installed one library but the problem work like this, in console line python recognize my import and the code i trying work fine:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LJtA.png
and when use the "WinPython command prompt" for call my example and execute, the console show me this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JVbV.png

Console show `AttributeError: "module" objec has no attribute %name%`

this is the code:

```
import heatmap
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pts = []
    for x in range(400):
        pts.append((random.random(), random.random()))
    print "Processing %d points..." % len(pts)
    hm = heatmap.Heatmap()
img = hm.heatmap(pts).save("classic.png")
```

Comment: Please include your code (and its output) as text in the question. Code in an image can't be copied and pasted to try it ourselves, and if the linked images ever disappears from the web, your question will become incomprehensible.

Comment: That said, this may be the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362851/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-atribute-ascii-lowercase), where you have a module of your own with the same name as the library you've installed. Perhaps try `print heatmap.__file__` to see if you're getting the module you expect?

Comment: thanks for you response! and console show this:  NameError: name 'heatmap' is not defined but i try to do the same code example and do what i want.

Comment: Hello, i import first heatmap and use `print heatmap.__file__` and then show me this `heatmap.pyc`

Comment: That makes it sound like you had a local `heatmap.py` file that you've renamed, but the compiled module file, `heatmap.pyc`, is still around and getting imported instead. Try looking for it either in the same folder as your script or in a subfolder named `__pycache__`.

Comment: already check that and i dont have the subfolder named `__pycache__`, i uninstall and delete all library heatmap i reinstalled to and i have the same error

Comment: The `__file__` string should tell you where the `pyc` file is coming from. If it is not an absolute path, then the file is located relative to the folder you're running your script in. Just delete the file, and you should be set.